# Ink-Mails - Using Block-Grid has no effect for mail clients

Tags: android, css, gmail, zurb-foundation, zurb-ink

I'm having trouble by displaying a block grid when using the Ink-Framework of Zurb.

The block-grid elements doesn't pushed down to the next row if the viewport 
gets smaller using e.g. the GMail mobile client.

I have tried many things, then i just start to inline the block-grid example:

http://zurb.com/ink/docs/examples/basic-block-grid.html

of zurb self, and the result was the same. The E-Mail still not readable using the mobile
GMail client, but Zurb recommends to use block-grids since gmail doesn't support media queries.

Now im confused, is this a problem of the zurb framework or the gmail client?

Using GMail-App on Android (device: Galaxy SIII): [Picture](https://familie-bechler.noip.me/owncloud/public.php?service=files&t=730bd3335e520e0dd7ba44e235baa358)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem and it turned out that my DOCTYPE was being stripped out by my CSS Inlining process.

Check that you're correctly using the XHTML Doctype given in Zurb's boilerplate

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Leaving this out or using another doctype can cause the `td.block-grid` elements to resize with the parent table. Including the doctype causes the `td.block-grid` elements to keep their width where possible and re-flow onto the next lines instead

Unfortunately, although I investigated a little, I haven't yet been able to identify the difference in specs which causes this behaviour

**Also remember** - if you've been writing your email as HTML4 or HTML5, and are now adding the XHTML doctype, you should make sure the rest of your markup is compatible with XHTML. In particular, ensure you are using self-closing meta tags, or when you add the XHTML doctype some mobile clients may ignore your meta viewport tag